# Apply specific function as modifier on f-curve

Tags: modifiers, transforms, audio, fcurves

I am a complete beginner in Blender and 3-D Modelling in general. Currently I am trying to understand f-curves and what you can do with them, because I mainly want to create Audio Responsive Animations.

I know how to bake sound to a F-Curve, with which I have my own problems. What I am currently trying to accomplish is the following.

I want to bake sound to an F-Curve and apply a modifier as such:

If the value (let's say my animated property is the objects size) is 0, I want the curve to be at 0.
If it is bigger, I want it to be 1.

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:
Lets say I have an infinite animation loop of sorts. If there is sound, I want it to play the animation. If there is no sound, I want it to freeze and maybe change tint (so i get the effect of it being 'disabled'). Preferably, I'd like to have some interpolation between the changes from 0->1 or 1->0.

Would that be the way to go about this?

If yes, how do you apply actual specific functions, in this case a simple 'Step'-function to an F-Curve. I didn't have any luck with trying the built-in F-Curve modifiers.

Comment: I would think you would need to write a script for that, but I could be wrong.

Comment: i would try that with animation nodes